# Calculating an average according to a Gaussian distribution

Tags: field-theory, path-integral

I want to calculate the following average :
$$ \langle \exp{\left[ i \sum_{\alpha} q_{\alpha}h(\vec{x}_{\alpha})\right]}\rangle$$

Where the summation is over a finite number of specific points and $q$s are some real numbers.

According to the weight :
$$ \wp \lfloor h(\vec{x}) \rfloor \propto \exp{\left[-\frac{K}{2}\int dx^2 (\nabla h)^2\right]}$$

I mean the following expression:

$$ \langle \exp{\left[ i \sum_{\alpha} q_{\alpha}h(\vec{x}_{\alpha})\right]}\rangle= \frac{\int d\lfloor h(\vec{x})\rfloor \exp{\left[ i \sum_{\alpha} q_{\alpha}h(\vec{x}_{\alpha})\right]}\exp{\left[-\frac{K}{2}\int dx^2 (\nabla h)^2\right]} }{\int d\lfloor h(\vec{x})\rfloor \exp{\left[-\frac{K}{2}\int dx^2 (\nabla h)^2\right]} }$$

I use the Fourier transformation of $h$ and find the result :
$$ \exp{\left[ \frac{1}{4 \pi K} \sum_{\alpha , \beta} q_{\alpha}q_{\beta} \ln{|\vec{x}_{\alpha}-\vec{x}_{\beta}|}\right]}$$

But it seems that the result is equal to above result only when $\sum q_{\alpha}=0$ and is zero otherwise. But I couldn't have found any gap in my calculations, going to Fourier space and then completing the square gives the aforementioned result. What's wrong with my calculation?

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could define your notation and all the quantities that you use in the expressions.

Comment: @flippiefanus I made some clarifications, I hope that they will be useful.

Comment: I assume your average is an ensemble average. So one of the quantities in the expression should be elements of such an ensemble. I cannot identify this quantity. What is the funny p in the second expression? Perhaps I don't understand enough of the background of this problem, but I think you could perhaps provide some of this background so that you question would be more widely useful.